# Source for small Touch-Panels?

Tags: touch-panel, touchscreen, kits

Is there a company that will sell me a touch panel similar to the IPhone or IPad surface, in single quantities, complete with a Developer Kit?

Can I get it in a specific form-factor (say, 2x7 inches)?

Comment: Can you clarify "similar to the iPhone or iPad" do you mean glass capacitive on color TFT?  Each of these points adds cost and complexity.  Which are essential to you?  Favorite-ing this so I can find it later...

Comment: Yeah, you can get small resistive touchscreens for super cheap, but I haven't found any good source for capacitive touchscreens. See my related question at: http://chiphacker.com/questions/259/capacitive-touchscreen-for-diy-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquidware sells touchscreen developer kits like: http://www.liquidware.com/shop/show/TSL/TouchShield+Slide

Sparkfun has some also: http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/advanced_search_result.php?keywords=touchscreen&x=0&y=0&search_section=products

Answer (score 0):

I always see the touchscreen controllers on Atmel's webpage on my way to their microcontrollers, but never stopped to look.

They have a 4.3" dev kit for their mXT224 maXTouch touchscreen controller [here](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=4621).

You'll notice that they **really** want you to register for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you are lucky enough to need a touch screen size which is equal to an existing mobile phone screen, you may be able to pick up screens through ebay or touchscreen repair outlets.